# How to Tie OpenEvent/ClickEvent to a particular email a subscriber actioned?

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#, fuel-sdk

I'm looking for some assistance on how to tie an OpenEvent or ClickEvent in Fuel SDK to the actual email that they took that action on.

I can pull back OpenEvent's and ClickEvent's just fine, but all it shows is when the subscriber opened something, but doesn't say what email they opened or what email they clicked a link on.

Does anyone have any assistance on correlating an open or click event to the actual email that was opened or clicked?

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 0):

The Send object would be the one that ties all of that together.  In the FuelSDK for C#, this would be ET_Send.  An example has been added to the repo at:
https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/Dot9/objsamples/Sample_Send.cs

When retrieving this object, it has a property for ID which is the same as the JobID you would see in tracking if using the ExactTarget UI.  The value of this property also corresponds to the SendID property that is available on tracking events.  In order to get to the actual Email that was sent, the Send object has a property for Email.ID.